# How to sliding photo gallery images like pagefolding in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone developing. Can any body tell me that how can i `scroll galley photos` one by one image like a folding view.

By folding view I mean the folding should work something like that for Flipboard app. In contrast to what `Flip-board` does, the view changes by flipping the screen view from bottom to top (or vice versa), I want to create the similar screen view change but happening for right to left (or vice versa), where the image (in gallery) folds from the center to show the next image.

Thanks

Comment: see this---->>>> http://rahulvirja.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-make-image-gallary-on-scrollview.html

Comment: what Acctually i want means i want to select some photos froms gallery after that i want to display that photos in next view and i sliding photo means it slid like a foldview type.right now its horizontally sliding photos.i want to slid like foldview

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own with animation.  Please check below URL

https://github.com/mpospese/MPFlipViewController

For Flip Board :  https://github.com/Reefaq/FlipView

Comment: MPFlipviewcontroller is not working.flipview is working but how can i apply this to photo gallery

Comment: You need to take all photo from photo library then arrange this photo with animation . For getting photo you need ALAsset library Please check this code also "https://github.com/romaonthego/REPhotoCollectionController" and "https://github.com/arturgrigor/AGImagePickerController"

Comment: hey after selecting some pictures from gallery its display images in next view ,when i sliding picture its horizontally scrolling but i want it like a foldingimage,when i slide the image it have to fold like a folding view,can u please tell how can i do that

Comment: :) You need to write custom code. Now you have images in one code and in second code you have flip view animation. merge both the things and create own one. In first code you can take how to put images from iPhone photo library and in second Put animation effect. Hope it make sence.

Comment: please tell me how to do this,or send me sample code for that please

Answer (score 0):

you can check this github code i have implemented this in my project and its work fine
https://github.com/kejinlu/PagedFlowView

Answer (score 0):

you should use UIScroollView With UIPageController 
i used [This](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/) Code It's work for me :)